Interacting with page that uses frames
I'm working with PuppeteerSharp interacting with a page that contains multiple frames. I believe it's a servlet.  My code is clicking a button to check for new orders, then if there are orders, it's selecting the order and clicking accept.
I have a couple different issues that I'm not sure why are happening. Here's a simplified version of my code, with some odd lines perhaps because I've been trying different things.  It will work fine on the first loop and most loops but sometimes it has issues and I don't know why.
Sometimes the line var rows = await loadTable.QuerySelectorAllAsync("tr") will give the error "Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation." and sometimes the error "Protocol error (DOM.resolveNode): Node with given id does not belong to the document"
Sometimes the line await goButton.ClickAsync(); will give the error "Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation."
Am I not waiting on something correctly?  I can't use WaitforNavigation becuase it's javascript navigation.
do{
    frameElement = await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("[name='_frame']");
    frame = await frameElement.ContentFrameAsync();

    await frame.WaitForSelectorAsync("[name='_work']");
    mainFrameElement = await frame.WaitForSelectorAsync("[name='_work']");
    mainFrame = await mainFrameElement.ContentFrameAsync();
    await mainFrame.GetContentAsync();                

    var goButton = await mainFrame.WaitForSelectorAsync("input[title='Go']");
    await goButton.ClickAsync();
        
    await mainFrame.WaitForSelectorAsync("#S1");
    
    var loadTable = await mainFrame.QuerySelectorAsync("#S1");
    await loadTable.WaitForSelectorAsync("tr");
    var rows = await loadTable.QuerySelectorAllAsync("tr");
    var rowCount = rows.Count();
    Console.WriteLine("RowCount: " + rows.Count());

    if (rowCount > 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loads found");
        for (int index = 1; index < rowCount; index++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Clicking on row " + index);
            await rows[index].ClickAsync();
            await loadTable.WaitForSelectorAsync("tr[class*='h']");
            await page.ScreenshotAsync("rowclicked.jpg");

            var currentRow = await (await loadTable.QuerySelectorAsync("tr[class*='h']")).QuerySelectorAllAsync("td");
            var SIDNumber = (await currentRow[4].GetPropertyAsync("innerText")).RemoteObject.Value.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("OrderNumber:" + SIDNumber);
        }
    }

} while (true);


Please share the page. If your code only works on the first loop, then you'll need to re-query any elements that were removed once you get back to the main page (or frame, whatever is on the site). JS SPA navigations are usually treated as navigations by Puppeteer.

The page requires a login to get to, so I can't really share the page itself.   I've tried the WaitForNavigation function after a click and and just get timeouts.   It works on more than just the first loop. The first loop always seems to work, but on subsequent loops, it may or may not work

You have a race condition, probably. WaitForNavigation needs to be set to begin listening before the click, then await it after clicking. Better yet, wait for a selector that only exists on the next page. If the page is behind auth, I suggest recreating a simple version that doesn't require auth and allows others to run the code, making it possible to help on an agreed upon reproduction. You can then apply that solution to your main problem, assuming the example you created isn't an oversimplification.

ggorlen, I thought WaitForNavigation was set after the click.  I tried the following and still got a timeout.  var navigationTask = page.WaitForNavigationAsync(new NavigationOptions { WaitUntil = new[] {  WaitUntilNavigation.Networkidle0 } });
await Task.WhenAll(navigationTask, goButton.ClickAsync());   I was trying the method to wait till an item was visible in the code I posted originally, but that doesn't see to be working all the time.   It doesn't go to a new page, but the Go button will just re-query the orders and load part of the page again.  At least that seems like what's happening

You're waiting for navigation before clicking which won't work. Change the order of your WhenAll. The flow is this: begin listening for nav to occur, click something that triggers nav, then await for the navigation to happen. WaitForSelector won't work if the selectors are the same on both pages before and after nav--you'll need to find a predicate that's different for the new page, like different item names, quantity or whatever.

I tried the other order for the WhenAll first.  It times out both ways.  The selectors are the same before and after nav, but they disappear while the page is loading. Maybe a way to wait for them to dissapear first?  That might take a small amount of time before that happens and sometimes it's being picked up right and sometimes not?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Sorry, there's nothing I can do without the site.
